# Android with TabHost and Lists

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I am writing an Android app that has a Tabs (3)

Each Tab should have a listview

I know that Java has a limitation of extending 1 class.

My current code is

```
public class AlbumsActivity extends Activity {
```

I would like to do this

```
public class AlbumsActivity extends Activity, ListActivity {
```

I come from the world of iOS so multiple inheritence is OK in Obj-C but I know its a big NO NO in Java.

So how do I solve this? I know its possible because Spotify has done it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ListActivity is a subclass of Activity, so you can simply use:

```
public class AlbumsActivity extends ListActivity
```

and you will get all the methods from both classes.

Answer (score 1):

It's enough to do:

```
public class AlbumsActivity extends ListActivity
```

[ListActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html) extends [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) anyway.